# No such file or directory linux shell script

Tags: linux, bash, docker, shell

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql -uroot -pwelcome1 < /home/sai/first.sql

echo "The program has completed"
```

I am trying to call a sql file from shell script ,I am running the script as `bash run.sh`, but it telling that there is no such directoryfirst.sql, but if i run that command separately as `mysql -uroot -pwelcome1 < /home/sai/first.sql`, it is working, is there a different way to write?

Comment: If this `directoryfirst.sql` isn't a typo in this question it is an indication that you forgot a `/` in your script.

Comment: It is not a typo,the error is showing in the same way@GeraldSchneider

Comment: Try the following: Remove the path from your script and type it again, then save your script. Don't copy&paste. I've seen invisible utf8 characters causing such trouble.

Comment: It is not woking @GeraldSchneider

Comment: If the script is really as simple as you show here, try creating a new one with the same commands. Type, _don't_ copy and paste, the commands into the new script and see if it does this same thing.

Comment: Run command in the console: `file /path-to-your-file/file-name.sql` - this will check that file really exists and the path is correct.

Comment: Yes i have cross checked that the path of sql file is correct by typing in the terminal@SergeySerov

Comment: Hey guys Issue solved by typing the same script using vi.Thanks for your help :p

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a line-ending issue.  If you open `run.sh` in vim, and run **`set fileformat=unix`** and the `+` appears (to show you that the file is now modified) it means that the file had DOS line endings, which Bash cannot interpret correctly.  Save and quit and the script should work.

It future, if something obviously weird is going on, please use a command like **`od -ctx1 run.sh`** to look at what is really in the file.

Comment: I agree this is a likely source of the problem. See ["Why would a correct shell script give a wrapped/truncated/corrupted error message?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31885409/why-would-a-correct-shell-script-give-a-wrapped-truncated-corrupted-error-messag) and ["Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings) for more info and options.